# Why UIView doesn't need QuartzCore.framework to work?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, core-animation, calayer

I realized that every views are backed up by a CALayer. 
So I was wondering why when we use UIView we don't need to import QuartzCore.framework in our project ?

I know we need to do it if we need to set properties like shadowOffset for example but I'm sure in its own implementation need to set these properties.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not accessing any CALayer properties or methods directly unless you change the properties of the UIView's layer.  Internally, UIView uses it.

**EDIT** The reason that you don't need to link it just to use UIView is because UIView is an already compiled library.  All of the symbols inside have already been resolved (or flagged as weak a.k.a. to be resolved at runtime) and so the compiler and linker just use them as they are.

Comment: Ok but if I create a framework using let's say mapkit.framework. If you want to use my custom framework you'll have to import it AND mapkit.framework right ?

Comment: No, I don't think you understand what "import" actually does.  You only need to import something if you directly use a function from it.  You need to **link** it of course, but you don't need to import it.

Comment: I didn't mean #import sorry. I meant link binary with libraries. I agree with you that I don't need to import QuartzCore but I should at least link QuartzCore in order for uikit/UIView to use CALayer no ?

Comment: Yes, by default all Xcode projects will link QuartzCore.  The reason that you don't need to to use UIView is that UIView is already compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `QuartzCore.framework` framework if you are using any classes of this framework.

And so `UIView` class is importing these framework.
**P.S.** importing a frmework doesn't mean that now you can use that framework. These frameworks are already in `iOS` you just import them so that you can suppress the compiler warnings and your project compiles successfully.

Comment: Ok but if I create a framework using let's say mapkit.framework. If you want to use my custom framework you'll have to import it AND mapkit.framework right ?

Comment: if your framework is compiled then I don't think you have to import mapkit.framework